# Virtual network connection does not delete after resource group deletion

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

We had a resource group that included ADLS V2 and a VNET (to which the ADLS was connected through a service connection).

The entire resource group was deleted but the virtual network connection to Azure Storage appears to still be hanging around somehow and is preventing a re-deploy of the same. The error received is:

> subnet with State NetworkSourceDeleted is required to be removed

Any idea how to resolve?

[image]

Comment: If there are still resources hanging, the resource group should not be fully deleted yet. Can you go int the VNET and remove any subnet delegations, service endpoints etc.? if that not helps, you should open a support ticket

Comment: The resource group is gone, the VNET connection is hanging around - that's the issue :)

Comment: that would be a really weird state then and indeed a support case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen because when an resource group is deleted, Azure deletes the service connections after the resource group is deleted. An error might have occurred during this connection deletion due to which this service connection was not deleted and remained in NetworkSourceDeleted state. You will need to delete the service association links of subnet Run following commands:

```
SAL_ID=$(az network vnet subnet show --resource-group $resourceGroupName --vnet-name $vnetName --name $subnetName --query id --output tsv)/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/serviceAssociationLinks/default

az resource delete --ids $SAL_ID --api-version 2018-07-01
```